# Drawing Polylines in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

The code below is an example from Microsoft to generate a polyline. I have already implemented this, but it does not work.

My question is: what is the method to make the "myPolyline" object to show? The last line in code is `myGrid.Children.Add(myPolyline)`, I do not understand which object is supposed to be the named "myGrid", maybe the answer to my question is related to this.

```
' Add a Polyline Element
Dim myPolyline As New Polyline()
myPolyline.Stroke = Brushes.SlateGray
myPolyline.StrokeThickness = 2
myPolyline.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd
Dim Point4 As New System.Windows.Point(1, 50)
Dim Point5 As New System.Windows.Point(10, 80)
Dim Point6 As New System.Windows.Point(20, 40)
Dim myPointCollection2 As New PointCollection()
myPointCollection2.Add(Point4)
myPointCollection2.Add(Point5)
myPointCollection2.Add(Point6)
myPolyline.Points = myPointCollection2
myGrid.Children.Add(myPolyline)
```

Comment: 'myGrid' should be a Grid on your window (e.g. defined in XAML). Most other panels will work, too.

Comment: does it mean a Grid control? or an instance of something?

Comment: @GeurysNovas Your comment on competent_tech's answer is putting doubt on what you are trying to do and what technology you are using. PolyLine is part of WPF, so his answer is correct. What technology are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

`myGrid` is just the default `Grid` that is added to a WPF form with a name of myGrid applied:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
</Grid>
```

The sample that you show the code from points to the example page [How to: Draw a Polyline by Using the Polyline Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747354.aspx), which in turn contains a link to a downloadable sample project also contains examples for other shape elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I think I must test with samples, I am using windows aplicattion form not WPF, so I need to know if this code will work.

Comment: No, this code won't work in WinForms, it is specific to WPF. To draw in winforms, you need to use graphics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyh3c8h8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A comparable function in Winforms would be the [Graphics.DrawLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ewkcdb3.aspx) Method or [Graphics.DrawPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath) Method, which you would use in the Paint Event of the Control you are wishing to draw on.

quick example:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    Dim myPen As Pen = New Pen(Brushes.DarkGray, 2)
    Dim myPoints() As Point = New Point() {New Point(1, 50), New Point(10, 80), New Point(20, 40)}
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(myPen, myPoints)
End Sub
```

and DrawPath example:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    Dim myPen As Pen = New Pen(Brushes.DarkGray, 2)
    Dim path As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath = New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath

    path.AddLine(New Point(1, 50), New Point(10, 80))
    path.AddLine(New Point(10, 80), New Point(20, 40))
    path.CloseFigure()

    e.Graphics.DrawPath(myPen, path)
End Sub
```